# Adjust Width of drop-down combo box Button Win32

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am using the Combo Box Control to display a drop-down.

The problem is that the OS sets the width of the button on the right. (Drop-Down trigger button).
I know that there is a message to set the width of the drop-down list. (That's what most answer/question) are about when searching for this topic but I couldn't find anything in documentation whether it is possible to set/modify the **width** of that trigger-**button**. Is it even possible?

Thank you.

Comment: No, the control doesn't support that being changed as far as I know.

Comment: Why do you want to change the size of the arrow button? What is the use-case for this?

Comment: Could you explain why you need to do this? As far as I know, the size of the arrow button cannot be changed.